# Can I somehow add the configuration that suppresses rules to version control?

Tags: visual-studio, sonarlint

I'm using the SonarLint plugin for Visual Studio to work on a C++ code base. So far, SonarLint is *very* helpful but there are a couple of rules that I simply cannot take into considerations. When excluding those rules, SonarLint generates the `settings.json` file in
`%APPDATA%\SonarLint for Visual Studio` that contains the corresponding rules.

This works, but the issue I'm having is that this is a purely local setting which means that every developer needs to have the same content in the `settings.json` file so that it works for the whole team.

Is there a way to have the list of suppressed rules in a file that is part of my Git repository and SonarLint takes it from there?

Comment: One solution could be to use SonarLint in connected mode, the rules from SonarQube or SonarCloud would be automatically applied to everyone using it.